# Source for 3 and only 3 Temples

Tags: sources-mekorot, number, beis-hamikdash, yirmiyahu--book-of

Is [Yirmiyahu 7:4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1107.htm#4) the source for the idea that there won't be a 4th Temple?
If not, what is?

> ד  אַל-תִּבְטְחוּ לָכֶם, אֶל-דִּבְרֵי הַשֶּׁקֶר לֵאמֹר:  הֵיכַל יְהוָה
>   הֵיכַל יְהוָה, הֵיכַל יְהוָה הֵמָּה.‏
>   4. Trust ye not in lying words, saying: 'The temple of the LORD, the temple of the LORD, the temple of the LORD, are these.'

Edit:
Rashi says this refers to the shalosh regalim, what is his source for that?

Comment: Why would you think someone lying while saying "temple" three times means there will be three temples? Does the context there suggest that to you? To me it sounds like God is telling the people what they're doing isn't good enough and if the people start behaving better there will be no exiles at all.

Answer (score 1):

Chapter 40 and subsequent chapters of the prophecy of Yechezkel deal with the third temple.

In [Chapter 43 (7)](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16141) he says

> And He said to me, Son of man, [this is] the place of My throne and
>   [this is] the place of the soles of My feet where I shall dwell in the
>   midst of the Children of Israel **forever**, and the House of Israel
>   will no longer defile My Holy Name, etc.”

Please notice the word “forever” which implies that there will not be another temple. Please also see the explanation of the [Malbim](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39980&st=&pgnum=268) who describes the dwelling of the Divine Presence there as  שכינת קבע - a fixed dwelling.

Comment: Is לעולם really not used in any other description of the conquest of Israel/Jerusalem or the other Temples?

Comment: Actually, Yechezkel is talking about the second temple.  But the second temple was not built that way, so we say it talks about the third. But it might also be talking about the 4th or 5th or 10th.

Comment: @DoubleAA If I remember correctly, "forever" is also mentioned in reference to the Mishkan.

Comment: @avi What you mean to start your comment with is: Actually we have no idea what number Temple Yechezkel is talking about. (Not unlike many of his other prophecies...)

Comment: Rabbi Frankel (Educational Coordinator at OU) in his [article](http://www.ou.org/torah/frankel/haftarot/tetzaveh60.htm) subtitles it "Construction and Inauguration of the Eternal Temple" and says: "an opinion cited in RASHI that this relates to the Second Temple, is based on the idea that that one could have been the Temple of the Mashiach, if not for the fact that "sin intervened," and the Repentance, of the People was inadequate, and the Redemption was pushed off into the future."

The Haftarah also describes the Dedication of that Great Temple in the Messianic Age.

Comment: @DoubleAA I think the context is pretty clear, that if you were living during the first exile, you would assume this was talking about the second temple.  It's really the only excuse for the majority to have stayed in Bavel even after the Temple was constructed.

Answer (score 1):

In the book Holy Temple Revisited Rabbi Reznik claims that Bar Kochva built one and perhaps others as well (based on talmudic and midrashic sources )

Comment: You should copy in the quote you are citing so we can see exactly what is said.

Answer (score 0):

The [Book of Haggai](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2201.htm) begins with divine dissatisfaction with the returning exiles for failing to build the Second Temple. When they do start building, God is unimpressed. Nonetheless, He encourages Zerubabel and Joshua, and says (Hag 2:6):

> כִּי כֹה אָמַר יְהוָה צְבָאוֹת, **עוֹד אַחַת** מְעַט הִיא; וַאֲנִי, מַרְעִישׁ אֶת-הַשָּׁמַיִם וְאֶת-הָאָרֶץ, וְאֶת-הַיָּם, וְאֶת-הֶחָרָבָה.
>
> <sup>*For thus saith the LORD of hosts: **Yet once**, it is a little while, and I will shake the heavens, and the earth, and the sea, and the dry land*</sup>

(emphasis mine)

[Metzudat David says](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14261&st=&pgnum=309) that "Yet once" refers to the Second Temple, which will only last "a little while", before being destroyed, as if the heavens, earth, sea, and dry land are being shaken. According to him, verse 7 is referring to the coming redemption.

So as of the beginning of the Second Temple, There will be "*one* more" exile and destruction before God reveals Himself, implying that the third Temple will be the last.

Comment: Did you check any classical commentaries to see if they agree?

Comment: @DoubleAA how'd I do? He doesn't say it in so many words, but its implied in the way I originally wrote.

Comment: That verse does not say there will be three and only three temples. If this is the whole basis of saying there will be three and only three temples, that's pretty flimsy.

Comment: @AL correct. It says there will be one more temple before the redemption, which *implies* that there will be 3 and only 3.

Comment: @BabySeal It does not say there will be one more temple before the redemption either. It sounds like it says that in a short period of time (not 2500 years) God will again shake the heavens and earth to encourage the nations to recognize that (2nd) Temple.

Comment: @AL, that seems like a valid interpretation, but it sounds differently to me (and to the Metzudat David).

Comment: @BabySeal You are absolutely right. I guess my criticism is that being vague, it's not a great source. In terms of Metzudat David, it sounds like even that is open to interpretation, because you didn't quote where he said (if he says it) that the Third Temple will be the final one. Of course you can infer from lots of places referring to David's kingdom being eternal or such that there will ultimately be some final temple. But 3? Tho I have a feeling this is discussed in the Talmud, for such a widespread belief it should come from something more substantial that the sources you have outlined.

Comment: The rest of the prophesy also only discusses "this" (2nd) Temple. Also Haggai 2:21-23 confirms that it was referring only to the 2nd Temple and Zerubabel, not the far future. Rashi also disagrees with Metzudat David (although I don't agree with Rashi either) and says that this is talking about events relating to the Greeks and Persians. And again, even if you were right and it does refer to a future Temple, the question was about how we know there will be *only* three temples, as opposed to four (for example), and your answer did not address that.

Comment: Disagree, I would say that avoiding to MD it discusses the 3rd, not the second. And the verse says one more. That is the inference.

Comment: @AL, basically this is how I'm reading Haggai. God wants the Jews to build the Temple and is dissatisfied with their complacence. That's the first chapter.

Comment: @AL in the second chapter, God is basically unimpressed with the Jews' efforts and with their character. He is essentially rejecting the second  temple and saying that it is nothing compared to the first. Then starting with verse 6, there are four positive verses. God says that after "one more" something the temple will be filled with the riches of nations, and it will be greater than the first. Then he goes back to calling the Jews impure.

Comment: @AL my understanding and Metzudat David's (read it, I've provided a link and will go line by line with you), is that the 4 positive verse are referring to the redemption we await. He also says that there will be *one more* house here, the second temple, and that will be destroyed, and then the third temple will be built and be better than the first. The one more is the important part.

Comment: @al one more temple that doesn't last, and then all the nations will come and pay tribute, and God will be revealed as the provider of wealth. If this temple weren't the last, th verse wouldn't say "once more". It would just say that this one won't last. And RAshi can disagree. That doesn't diminish MD