# Will the third Temple be eternal? And if so, what does that mean?

Tags: beis-hamikdash

There is a concept mentioned in connection with the third Temple that it is going to be *completely* (or permanently) eternal (for example: [Pesachim 88a](http://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.88a.4?lang=he&with=Rashi&lang2=he) following Chiddushei Aggadot Maharsha and Rashi to Chullin 91b and [Zohar to parshat Pinchas 221a, section 148-149](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14250&st=&pgnum=54)), Zohar 1:28a, [Tikkunei Zohar, Tikkun 8](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9557&st=&pgnum=135) and [Sefer HaMa'amarim Meluket, vol. 4, parshat Mattot-Mase](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=25071&st=&pgnum=137)i. This is often associated with the phrase *You bring them in and plant them in the mountain of Your inheritance, the place, HaShem, which You have made for  You to dwell in, the Mikdash, HaShem, which Your hands have established.* (Shemot 15:17)

This quality distinguishes the third Temple from both the first Temple, whose *sanctity* (קדושה) was eternal by most opinions, which means that its sanctity remains to this day and the second Temple, which is on a lower level than even the first Temple.

What is this quality of the third Temple and how is it acquired according to the plain sense of things?

Comment: "the first Temple, whose sanctity (קדושה) was eternal by most opinions" I don't even know what it means for a Temple to have eternal sanctity. Do you mean the stones can't be used for other things? The common discussion of קדושה ראשונה קידשא לעתיד לבוא refers to the sanctification of the land on the Temple Mount (and possibly Yerushalayim) and by extension the prohibition of Bamot.

Comment: "There is a concept mentioned" Can you [edit] to provide an example of such a mention? The earlier the better IMO.

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33930/759

Comment: The Sanctity of the first Temple remains in both the location of the altar and that local bimahs have ever since been prohibited, which is why we can't have sacrifices nowadays.

Comment: @CashCow That is correct according to the majority view which is what we follow. There is a minority view which does not accept the idea that the sanctity of the first Temple remains.

Comment: I don't see what you are referring to on Pesachim 88

Comment: You just quoted many passages from the Talmud and Zohar that say that the Third Temple will be the final one and eternal. What more proof do you need?

Comment: @ezra Like I mentioned, it also says that the quality of  'eternal' relates to the first Temple. But it was destroyed physically. This question is trying to understand what this means in regard to the third Temple, which is different from both the first and second Temples. And to understand how this state of being is accomplished whatever it may mean.