How Many Exiles Can There Be?
Parashat Bechukotai is coming up in which we get the short blessings followed by long curses for failure to follow the Torah in the land. I had always interpreted our right to live in the land to always have these terms and conditions, and therefore we could be exiled potentially an unlimited number of times for not following these rules.
However I've met other Jews who say this last exile was "the last final exile" and therefore they don't think "we could ever be kicked out of the land of Israel again." Where does this idea come from?

Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33930/759

The sages teach that there are four exiles, corresponding to the four kingdoms mentioned in the dreams in the book of Daniel, and we are now holding by the fourth exile.

Where do they do so?

Please provide sources if you have them.
